# if-else condition for update a table in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I want to update some data in a specified case, else these columns are not to be updated.

What can I write code in a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Help us help you by providing more detail, like an example.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `case` to control whether you assign a new value or keep the old value.

```
update <sometable>
set field = case when <condition> then <newvalue> else field end
where <condition>
```

Example:

```
update questions
set reply = case when @input is not null then @input else reply end
where answer = 42
```

Comment: @devio: Yes, for the specific case where the condition is a check for null, the isnull function can be used instead of a case, but I wanted to show the case as it can be used for any kind of condition. :)

Comment: @Guffa: +1 for this being my preferred solution as well. Maybe you should edit your answer and change "@input is not null" to "<some condition applies>" to make clear that field update will occur if some condition applies, independent of @input.

Comment: @Thorsten: Good point, I edited the anwer to have a pseudo code that shows the principle and an example.

Comment: take care bro!!!

Answer (score 6):

Use Case statement in Update clause

like

SQL Statement #6

```
UPDATE titles
       SET price =
                 CASE
                   WHEN (price < 5.0 AND ytd_sales > 999.99)
                                   THEN price * 1.25
                   WHEN (price < 5.0 AND ytd_sales < 1000.00)
                                   THEN price * 1.15
                   WHEN (price > 4.99 AND ytd_sales > 999.99)
                                   THEN price * 1.2
                   ELSE price
                 END
```

Taken from [SQL SERVER UPDATE](http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm)

Also you can go with if..else statement

If you would have been in SQL SERVER 2008, you could have avail the flavor of MERGE statement

Answer (score 3):

Just an example:

```
IF @a <= 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET counter = @a, name = 'Minati'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET name = 'Minati'
END
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can build the condition in the update command and easily run more than one update with the diferent conditions. It may not be the most elegant way but it is prety eficient. It depends of your needs.

```
UPDATE table SET field=value WHERE <<condition>>
UPDATE table SET field=value2 WHERE <<condition2>>
```